# webpart connection between 4 lists

Tags: 2013, connected-web-parts

I would like to add a connection between 4 lists.

When selecting an item from list 1 the related items will be displayed automatically in other 3 list.

the relation between 4 list is straight forward  list 1 connected to list 2 , list 2 connect to list 3 and list 3 connected to list 4.

Is it possible ? any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Not without serious coding. SharePoint is not a Relational Database.. Look into PowerApps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all list views on a page and connect them using "Connections" in order of dependency. Reference to the same is [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-data-in-Web-Parts-C9A84132-44BE-4ABB-94D1-D69CFDC052DB)

Comment: I checked this link but the data is not displayed automatically for all list from the first selection in list1! please help

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. It does seem to work the way you expect it. You may want to add master id in all associated list to achieve the same.